# Find whether a string is a subsequence in java

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I was going through online Java coding questions and i got one in which we need to write a function to find whether string1 contains all characters of a definite word and in same order as they appear in the definite word.
Like suppose input is

```
String1  =  "asgtoiawercbbk"
```

and our word is `stack`, then output should be `TRUE` (explanation: a**s**g**t**oi**a**wer**c**bb**k** ).

I am not able to find the approach. This what I was trying:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "asgtoiawercbbk";
        String s2 = "stack";

        if(s1.matches(s2))
            System.out.println("true");
        else
            System.out.println("false");

    }
```

but the output I was getting is false. I am not able to get the approach to check string one character by one character.

Comment: I would use `String#toCharArray`, check if the `char` is in the inputted String, keep the index and see if  `indexOf()` of the next `char` is greater than the previous

Comment: Although, I am betting a Regular Expression could resolve this as well

Answer (score 3):

A correct answer to this, if it's an online coding question, will depend heavily on what constraints you've been given. The easiest way to check whether a `String s` contains the word `stack` would be

```
s.matches(".*s.*t.*a.*c.*k.*");
```

I'll leave you to work out how to turn a given word into something with `.*` in between each pair of characters.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need the beginning and ending `.*`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yes, you do.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes test it and you will know.

Comment: Alright. @Pshemo I'm on mobile at the moment; I can't test.

Comment: @Pshemo And they are incredibly fiddly on mobile, if they work at all.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes We could go with this discussion longer, but lets stop it now. I could say that level of comfort doesn't matter if you really want to test something, but you could say that I am mistaken (just like that). I could say then to use simpler online IDE, then you could say "I don't know about any", I could say "then search for them and check how comfortable they are for you" but you could say "it is not worth spending my time on that". We could both exchange valid points but lets just agree do disagree, since this discussion is not relevant to OP question.